# building a datastructure to generate a mapping of one_hot vectors to images of different classes listed in a directory of image files

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding, tfrecord

Asking for help!!

Hellow everyone im working on my first non MNIST BS! computer vision project with deep learning, and im facing difficulties regarding the input data pipeline.

my problem is the following:

i use the tensorflow framework/python

i have a dataset of images files structured as follows:
    -each label folder is contained in the root directory named 'images'
    -each image is contained in their corresponding label subfolder

```
    e.g images/tomatoes/1.jpg
```

there are six classes in total (apples,avocados,bananas,mangoes,passionfruit,tomatoes)

i want to generate one_hot vectors for each label and  each vector should be associated with the files of the 
corresponding class(label)

given that im working with tensorflow, i want to convert my dataset into a tfrecord format in order to use the tf.Dataset API, im struggling to create a datastructure that will map  each of the 6 one_hot vectors to all the images in the dataset given their respective classes.

i've seen some code examples on github, but they only gave me half the solution this is what i've tried so far:

i've written subroutines to handle the image loading and preprocessing steps and i've also found on github one for converting the dataset(train,test,validation) into a tfrecord but where i'm stumbling is when loading the files and mapping them to their one_hot vectors with the glob module

this is what i've tried so far

```
#generate one_hot vectors given a directory name
#found it on github and added some tweaks
#this is returning a list of one_hot vectors given the number of classes

    import numpy as np

    def one_hot(directory,num_classes=6):

        labels = os.listdir(directory)
        label_scalars = [x for x in range(len(labels))]
        label_scalars = np.asarray(label_scalars)
        num_labels = label_scalars.shape[0]
        index_offset = np.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
        labels_one_hot = np.zeros((num_labels,num_classes))
        labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + label_scalars.ravel()] = 1
        return labels_one_hot


    #create a tfrecord given images addresses and their labels
    #found it on github

def createDataRecord(out_filename, addrs, labels):
    # open the TFRecord file
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(out_filename)
    for i in range(len(addrs)):
        #print how many images are saved every 100 images
        if not i% 100:
            print('Train data : {}/{}'.format(i,len(addrs)))
            sys.stdout.flush()

        #load the image
        img = load_image(addrs[i])

        label = labels[i]

        if img is None:
            continue

        #create a feature dict
        feature = {
            'image_raw': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()),
            'label': _int64_feature(label)
        }
        #create an example protocol buffer
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

        #serialize to string and writer on the file
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()



#load the images

addresses = glob.glob('images/*/*.jpg')

# 'images' is the root directory for the files
labels = one_hot('images')


# now the stumbling point, 
#create the datastructure to shuffle the data

from random import shuffle

c = list(zip(addresses,labels))
shuffle(c)
addresses,labels = zip(*c)
```

--->this data structure reuturns only six mappings from the first subdirectory, not working the way i expect it to. as you can see here:

```
In [116]: labels = one_hot('images')


labels = labels.tolist()

In [121]: labels
Out[121]: 
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]


In [117]: addrs = glob.glob('images\*\*.jpg')

In [122]: c = list(zip(labels,addrs))

In [123]: c
Out[123]: 
[([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'images\\apples\\0.jpg'),
 ([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'images\\apples\\1.jpg'),
 ([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'images\\apples\\10.jpg'),
 ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'images\\apples\\11.jpg'),
 ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], 'images\\apples\\12.jpg'),
 ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], 'images\\apples\\13.jpg')]
```

can you guide me, or show me an approach that is used in the industry to crack this kind of task? your input will be welcome, Arnaud Wanet....